# SpecFlow - Find all scenarios from method step and Find all unimplemented steps

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, bdd, specflow

New to SpecFlow.

When specs project become larger, organizing files and refactoring Given/When/Then string become troublesome.

1. How to find Scenarios in feature file from method step. Sometimes I have a steps shared in a few scenarios and features but from the C# step method view how to 'Find All References' in feature file?
2. How to get all unimplemented scenario steps (font color purple) in all features files so that I can implement the steps. Currently when I `Run All` tests, no warn about unimplemented steps left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning with version 1.9, SpecFlow supports these things (refer to [What's new in v1.9](http://www.specflow.org/whatsnew-19/)):

- **ad 1.:** Context menu in step definition: "Go To SpecFlow Step Definition Usages" (shortcut Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S):
- **ad 2.:** Context menu in feature file: "Generate Step Definitions"