# How to verify if all SpecFlow scenario steps are bound to methods

Tags: specflow

Is there a posibility to verify it for project, or better, whole solution?
It is posible for single feature file:
[SpecFlow - Find all scenarios from method step and Find all unimplemented steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000125/specflow-find-all-scenarios-from-method-step-and-find-all-unimplemented-steps)

But I want to check whole solution if everything is ok.
Running all tests verifies it, but it takes time - I want to do this before running tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The step definition report can find unbound steps as well as unused step definitions:
specflow.exe stepdefinitionreport {SpecFlowProjectName}.csproj

More information, see here: http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Reporting/

Comment: It works perfect for single csproj, but if project A references steps from project B via stepAssembly these steps are marked yellow (not defined). Is there a possibility to generate reaport in such case for steps referenced from other assemblies?

Comment: I believe this bug is fixed in upcoming v2 https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/pull/504 which is available in beta from nuget